# Template matching poor results cv2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, template-matching

I'm using template matching function from cv2 library in python to detect gandhi's potrait in indian currency note for fake currency detection. I'm taking the template by cropping the source image itself and then trying to match it however it is not able able to match if threshold is greater than 0.21.

Here is the source image:[image]

Here is the cropped image of grayscaled source image used as template: [image]

and here is the code that i'm using for template matching:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np
grayscale_image = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/files/50.jpg')
grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(grayscale_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/template.PNG'
template_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
template_image = cv2.cvtColor(template_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
h,w = template_image.shape[::]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(grayscale_image,template_image,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
plt.imshow(res,cmap='gray')
threshold = 0.25
loc=np.where(res>=threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
  cv2.rectangle(grayscale_image,pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
cv2_imshow(grayscale_image)
```

Comment: it's not multi-scale. check your pictures.

Comment: Your template is smaller than the same figure in your larger image.  Template matching is scale dependent. It does not work if the two features are not the same size. Also TM_COEFF_NORMED is not the best metric. Use TM_CORR_NORMED or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED.

Comment: Resize your template or larger image so that the figure in both images are the same size. Or crop your template from the larger image and do not resize it.

Comment: I have cropped the image from larger image only and have not resized it, moreover the shape of larger image is (690,1680) and smaller image is (392,280) around which kind of i think is similar to what in larger image @fmw42

Comment: `@Jinay Shah` Sorry, but they are not the same size. I have downloaded both images and viewed them at full resolution and the template is clearly much smaller than the feature in the larger image.